# Twisted new logger api print literal curly brackets?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I want to print a string contains "{}" and I am using the new logger api of twisted now: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logger.html

But I find that the new api can not print string like this:

```
from twisted.logger import Logger, STDLibLogObserver, globalLogPublisher
import logging

log = Logger()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

globalLogPublisher.addObserver(STDLibLogObserver())
a_str = "env={}".format({})
log.info(a_str)
```

Comment: Would note that this is one of two places (neither of which is in the doc) that i've seen the call `globalLogPublisher.addObserver(STDLibLogObserver())` actually spelled out, and it was crucial for getting the `Logger` to log simply etc. Also, one doesn't seem to need to import or configure the stdlib `logging` for this to actually log to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by escaping the braces with more braces:

```
a_str = "env={{}}"
```

Note that in case you expected `a_str = "env={{}}".format({})` to equal this string, it does not.  Read up on the quoting/escaping rules used by `format`.

However, you should log structured events instead.  Try this with your setup, instead:

```
log.info(format="env={env}", env={})
```